# location of "web-app" folder in development phase

Tags: grails

During my grails app development phase (when I compile and run using `grails run-app`), all my static files reside in **web-app** folder as usual.

Is there a way (using config or command line parameter) I can use a different directory, say **web-app2** for my static files? Something like `grails run-app -Dgrails.static.loc=~/web-app2 run-app`?

I need this only for development time. For production and deployment, I'm fine with the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

in your config.groovy you can set environment-specific configurations,

sth like

```
environments {
  development {
    grails.resources.work.dir = '/webapp-2/'
    grails.resources.uri.prefix = '/staticstuff/'
  }
  production {
    grails.resources.work.dir = '/webapp/'
    grails.resources.uri.prefix = '/static/'
  }
}
```

you can start your application with

```
grails dev run-app  // runs with the "development" data source
grails prod run-app // runs with the production data source
```

I tryed it out, works well!

have a look at http://www.grails.org/Environments and http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html